# Woocommerce How can I display product attributes under product title on catalog page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have a WordPress, WooCommerce based shop and I was wondering how can I display product attributes under product title on catalog page?

I guess it's just a filter needed to add, but how can I grab the values of the attributes of each product?

### Thanks in advance to everyone who tries to help, Have a great day =)

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 2):

According to your query i can to use on **wc_get_product_terms()** method for this case as

in the products loop use

```
global $product;
$colors = array_shift( wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, 'pa_color', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) ) );
```

Otherwise

```
global $product;
$colors = $product->get_attribute( 'pa_color' );
```

OR using get_post_meta  wp machanism as

```
$pa_color = get_post_meta($product->id, 'pa_color', true);
```

So use ,what are you want from above.

Thank you